# How to set the hand cursor on a mouse move for all buttons in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, mousemove

I've been setting each button's events manually, but how can I generalize this?

I suppose I could override ButtonBase, but how do I do that? I'm a relatively new C# programmer and I need this because I'm simulating a real device, so I need the cursor to change so the user will know where they can click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all the buttons are on the form (no nesting containers) then you can do something like this on `Form_Load()`

```
foreach(Button b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    b.MouseEnter += (s, e) => b.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    b.MouseLeave += (s, e) => b.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
}
```

If you don't want to touch every button on the form, you can do a simple collection and iterate over them

```
Button[] buttons = new[] {button1, button2, button3};

foreach (Button b in buttons)
{
    b.MouseEnter += (s, e) => b.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    b.MouseLeave += (s, e) => b.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
}
```

Comment: Simple, effective and real-code saver! It works, and I loved it!

Comment: If `b.Cursor` is supposed to be the cursor that is displayed when the mouse pointer is over the control, what's the point in setting it to `Arrow` on mouse leave? It would make more sense to set this only once and forget it.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new "Class Library" project and make a new class like this:

```
public class ExtendedButton:Button
{
    public ExtendedButton()
    {
        MouseEnter += (s, e) => Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        MouseLeave += (s, e) => Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }
}
```

On a Windows Form project, add a reference to your new library and on the form, add an ExtendedButton control instead of Button.

Comment: Best solution for this Issue.

Comment: that's just about what I want, but I just can't extend from Button, because if I'm coding in Class Library type, Visual Studio won't let me reference "using System", so this code won't work. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Do you have references on System and System.Windows.Forms in your Class Library project? Shows Visual Studio some specific error?

Comment: It won't allow me to reference them... The error is that it doesn't find System. I'll try to work this out a bit more and keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Visual Studio Designer. Select all buttons by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click'ing and change the [*Cursor* property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.cursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).